# How to initialize multiple dictionary in json in 1 NSObject using SwiftyJson

Tags: ios, swift4, nsobject, swifty-json

My API response is look like this

```
{
"error": false,
"id": "6",
"user_id": 7,
"users": [
    {
        "user_id": 1,
        "username": "spiderman"
    },
    {
        "user_id": 7,
        "username": "wonderwoman"
    }
    ],
"info": [
    {
        "id": 471,
        "message": "abc",
        "age": 10,
    }
    ]
}
```

I know how to initialize the value of `id`,`user_id` and `error` in NSOject. But I dont know how can I initialize the array of `users` and `info` in the same NSObject class.

Now I initialize the JSON like this

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON

class MyItem: NSObject {

    var userId : Int
    var error : Bool 
    var id : Int 

    init?(dict: [String :JSON]) {
        self.id = dict["id"]?.int ?? 0
        self.error = dict["error"]?.bool ?? false
        self.userId = dict["userId"]?.int ?? 0
    }
}
```

Now the problem is I don't know how to initialize data inside the `users` and `info` dictionary.How should I arrange it and how can I use it in other class

Kindly give an example.

Comment: @Venkat then how to access the data inside it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to create 2 different classes for user and info as follows:

```
class MyItem : NSObject {

    var error : Bool!
    var id : String!
    var info : [Info]!
    var userId : Int!
    var users : [User]!

    init(fromJson json: JSON!){
        if json == nil{
            return
        }
        error = json["error"].boolValue
        id = json["id"].stringValue
        info = [Info]()
        let infoArray = json["info"].arrayValue
        for infoJson in infoArray{
            let value = Info(fromJson: infoJson)
            info.append(value)
        }
        userId = json["user_id"].intValue
        users = [User]()
        let usersArray = json["users"].arrayValue
        for usersJson in usersArray{
            let value = User(fromJson: usersJson)
            users.append(value)
        }
    }
}

class User : NSObject {

    var userId : Int!
    var username : String!


    init(fromJson json: JSON!){
        if json == nil{
            return
        }
        userId = json["user_id"].intValue
        username = json["username"].stringValue
    }
}

class Info : NSObject {

var age : Int!
var id : Int!
var message : String!

init(fromJson json: JSON!){
    if json == nil{
        return
    }
    age = json["age"].intValue
    id = json["id"].intValue
    message = json["message"].stringValue
}
}
```

By doing this you would be able to directly access the value of user and info like for eg: `MyItem.users[index].userId`

Answer (score 2):

Use as below,

Root Class :-

```
import Foundation 
import SwiftyJSON


class RootClass : NSObject, NSCoding{

    var error : Bool!
    var id : String!
    var info : [Info]!
    var userId : Int!
    var users : [User]!


    /**
     * Instantiate the instance using the passed json values to set the properties values
     */
    init(fromJson json: JSON!){
        if json.isEmpty{
            return
        }
        error = json["error"].boolValue
        id = json["id"].stringValue
        info = [Info]()
        let infoArray = json["info"].arrayValue
        for infoJson in infoArray{
            let value = Info(fromJson: infoJson)
            info.append(value)
        }
        userId = json["user_id"].intValue
        users = [User]()
        let usersArray = json["users"].arrayValue
        for usersJson in usersArray{
            let value = User(fromJson: usersJson)
            users.append(value)
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns all the available property values in the form of [String:Any] object where the key is the approperiate json key and the value is the value of the corresponding property
     */
    func toDictionary() -> [String:Any]
    {
        let dictionary = [String:Any]()
        if error != nil{
            dictionary["error"] = error
        }
        if id != nil{
            dictionary["id"] = id
        }
        if info != nil{
            var dictionaryElements = [[String:Any]]()
            for infoElement in info {
                dictionaryElements.append(infoElement.toDictionary())
            }
            dictionary["info"] = dictionaryElements
        }
        if userId != nil{
            dictionary["user_id"] = userId
        }
        if users != nil{
            var dictionaryElements = [[String:Any]]()
            for usersElement in users {
                dictionaryElements.append(usersElement.toDictionary())
            }
            dictionary["users"] = dictionaryElements
        }
        return dictionary
    }

    /**
    * NSCoding required initializer.
    * Fills the data from the passed decoder
    */
    @objc required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
         error = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "error") as? Bool
         id = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "id") as? String
         info = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "info") as? [Info]
         userId = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "user_id") as? Int
         users = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "users") as? [User]

    }

    /**
    * NSCoding required method.
    * Encodes mode properties into the decoder
    */
    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder)
    {
        if error != nil{
            aCoder.encode(error, forKey: "error")
        }
        if id != nil{
            aCoder.encode(id, forKey: "id")
        }
        if info != nil{
            aCoder.encode(info, forKey: "info")
        }
        if userId != nil{
            aCoder.encode(userId, forKey: "user_id")
        }
        if users != nil{
            aCoder.encode(users, forKey: "users")
        }

    }

}
```

User Class :-

```
import Foundation 
import SwiftyJSON


class User : NSObject, NSCoding{

    var userId : Int!
    var username : String!


    /**
     * Instantiate the instance using the passed json values to set the properties values
     */
    init(fromJson json: JSON!){
        if json.isEmpty{
            return
        }
        userId = json["user_id"].intValue
        username = json["username"].stringValue
    }

    /**
     * Returns all the available property values in the form of [String:Any] object where the key is the approperiate json key and the value is the value of the corresponding property
     */
    func toDictionary() -> [String:Any]
    {
        let dictionary = [String:Any]()
        if userId != nil{
            dictionary["user_id"] = userId
        }
        if username != nil{
            dictionary["username"] = username
        }
        return dictionary
    }

    /**
    * NSCoding required initializer.
    * Fills the data from the passed decoder
    */
    @objc required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
         userId = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "user_id") as? Int
         username = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "username") as? String

    }

    /**
    * NSCoding required method.
    * Encodes mode properties into the decoder
    */
    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder)
    {
        if userId != nil{
            aCoder.encode(userId, forKey: "user_id")
        }
        if username != nil{
            aCoder.encode(username, forKey: "username")
        }

    }

}
```

Info Class :-

```
import Foundation 
import SwiftyJSON


class Info : NSObject, NSCoding{

    var age : Int!
    var id : Int!
    var message : String!


    /**
     * Instantiate the instance using the passed json values to set the properties values
     */
    init(fromJson json: JSON!){
        if json.isEmpty{
            return
        }
        age = json["age"].intValue
        id = json["id"].intValue
        message = json["message"].stringValue
    }

    /**
     * Returns all the available property values in the form of [String:Any] object where the key is the approperiate json key and the value is the value of the corresponding property
     */
    func toDictionary() -> [String:Any]
    {
        let dictionary = [String:Any]()
        if age != nil{
            dictionary["age"] = age
        }
        if id != nil{
            dictionary["id"] = id
        }
        if message != nil{
            dictionary["message"] = message
        }
        return dictionary
    }

    /**
    * NSCoding required initializer.
    * Fills the data from the passed decoder
    */
    @objc required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
         age = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "age") as? Int
         id = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "id") as? Int
         message = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "message") as? String

    }

    /**
    * NSCoding required method.
    * Encodes mode properties into the decoder
    */
    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder)
    {
        if age != nil{
            aCoder.encode(age, forKey: "age")
        }
        if id != nil{
            aCoder.encode(id, forKey: "id")
        }
        if message != nil{
            aCoder.encode(message, forKey: "message")
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do Like this,

```
class MyItem: NSObject {

    var userId : Int
    var error : Bool 
    var id : Int 
    var users : [[String:Any]] = []
    var info : [[String:Any]] = []

    init?(dict: [String :JSON]) {
        self.id = dict["id"]?.int ?? 0
        self.error = dict["error"]?.bool ?? false
        self.userId = dict["userId"]?.int ?? 0
        self.users = dict["users"] ?? []
        self.info = dict["info"] ?? []
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No offense to the developers of `SwiftyJSON`, it is a great library, but in Swift 4 to decode JSON `SwiftyJSON` became obsolete.

With the `Decodable` protocol you are able to decode the JSON without any extra code.

Create one struct including the two substructs, the coding keys are only necessary to map *snake_case* to *camelCase*.

```
struct MyItem: Decodable {

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case userId = "user_id", error, id, users, info}

    let userId : Int
    let error : Bool
    let id : String
    let users : [User]
    let info : [Info]

    struct User : Decodable {
        private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case userId = "user_id", username}
        let userId : Int
        let username : String
    }

    struct Info : Decodable {
        let message : String
        let id, age : Int
    }

}
```

Now decode the JSON

```
let jsonString = """
{
    "error": false,
    "id": "6",
    "user_id": 7,
    "users": [{"user_id": 1, "username": "spiderman"},{"user_id": 7,"username": "wonderwoman"}],
    "info": [{"id": 471,"message": "abc", "age": 10}]
}
"""

do {
    let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(MyItem.self, from: data)
    for user in result.users {
        print(user.userId, user.username)
    }
} catch { print(error) }
```

Comment: then how to use it mr?

Comment: I updated the answer adding to print all properties in `users`. Use completion. The compiler shows you what properties are available.